# Проблема с циклом в функции

Tags: php, циклы

```
$title = 123;

function page_template($name, $template) {
 global $title;

 $page = file_get_contents('system/pages/'.$name);
 $template_file = 'system/pages/templates/'.$template;
 $template_open = fopen($template_file, 'r');
 $template_gets = fgets($template_open, filesize($template_file));
 $template_explode = explode('|', $template_gets);
 $template_array_chunk = array_chunk($template_explode, 2);

 for($i = 0; $i <= count($template_array_chunk); $i++) {
  $patterns_page = '/'.$template_array_chunk[$i][0].'/i';
  $patterns_replace_page = $template_array_chunk[$i][1];
  eval("\$patterns_replace_page = \"$patterns_replace_page\";");

  $page_result = preg_replace($patterns_page, $patterns_replace_page, $page);
 }
return $page_result;
}

echo page_template('main.php', 'main.dat');
```

Почему не происходит замена? Однако, если return $page_result; поместить в сам цикл, то будет заменять некорректно и выводить одно и тоже несколько раз. Как решить проблему?

В файле main.dat находится следующее:

> \$USERNAME\$|$title|

Comment: А что вообще должно произойти?
Откуда внутри функции берется переменная $template_array_chunk?
Так же нигде не используются параметры функции - $a и $b.

Comment: Я уже не стал скидывать всё тело функции. А приложил то, в чём сама проблема. Мне просто нужно решить проблему: "Однако, если return $page_result; поместить в сам цикл, то всё будет заменять, но выводить одно и тоже несколько раз. Как решить проблему?"

Comment: Ну вообще всё должно работать..  Хотя для полного счастья надо увидеть полный код main.php и main.dat.

Выложи например на pastebin.com и кинь сюда ссылки

Кстати, использовать eval - плохой тон. Можно проще всё сделать

Comment: @Photon,

код main.php - http://pastebin.com/nC73j4wT,
код main.dat - http://pastebin.com/GsR5wy2z

Насчёт "проще". Я бы с удовольствием, вот изучаю всё, пытаюсь сделать что-то сам. Но пока до этого не допёрло :(

Comment: Этот код с этими файлами работает абсолютно без проблем. Так что я теперь опять не понимаю, в чём проблема :)

Comment: @Photon, а Вы попробуйте изменить содержимое main.dat на: \$USERNAME\$|$title|$USERID$|$title| и пропишите в main.php. И посмотрите, как оно будет работать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вряд ли кто-то ответит, потому что непонятно что входит и что должно выйти.
Единственное что бросилось в глаза это слеш перед $ в строке

```
eval ("\$patterns_replace_page = \"$patterns_replace_page\";");
```

Если только он должен стоять перед ковычкой. Если не то то нужно подробнее описать ситуацю.

Comment: Именно так..  Ответить на вопрос, в котором всё непонятно, потому что "Я уже не стал скидывать всё тело функции. А приложил то, в чём сама проблема." в принципе невозможно

Comment: @Димка, @Photon, отредактировал материал. Теперь, думаю, что всё понятно выложил.

Comment: ну теперь на сколько понял на места шаблона должен вбится какойто материал, но он не собирается в кучку ав переменной $page_result. Думается мне что последняя строка в цикле должна выглядеть примерно так

$page_result =$page_result.preg_replace($patterns_page, $patterns_replace_page, $page);

Comment: @Димка, неправильно понял..  Там же замена по очереди..

Comment: А ошибок никаких не пишет?

А на кусочек main.php можно взглянуть?

в строке
for($i = 0; $i <= count($template_array_chunk); $i++)
такой подход обычно делает обработку на 1 элемент массива больше чем есть.
Если например в массиве 3 элемента, то счет должен от 0 до 2, а в такой постановке будет от 0 до 3.
Ну это так по ходу дела.

Comment: @Димка, @Photon, смотрите. Должно заменять $USERNAME$ на $title, то есть на 123. Но выходит так: http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1348388384-clip-6kb.jpg, не понимаю, что я написал не так, что оно не заменяет.. Но если поместить return $result_page; в сам цикл, то оно заменяет что-то одно и при этом результат отображается несколько раз + некорректно.

Comment: После $page_result = preg_replace($patterns_page, $patterns_replace_page, $page);
добавь
 $page=$page_result;

а заодно и count($template_array_chunk)-1 сделай

Comment: @Димка, ура! Всё работает на отлично! Огромное Вам спасибо! +20 к вашему уважению добавляю :))